# Method for calculating distance between all points in a dataframe containing a list of xy coordinates

Tags: r, for-loop, math, apply

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I can't find the thread for the life of me!

I am trying to use r to produce a list of all the distances between pairs of xy coordinates in a dataframe. The data is stored something like this:

```
ID = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
x = c(1,2,4,5,1,3,1)
y = c(3,5,6,3,1,5,1)
df= data.frame(ID,x,y)
```

At the moment I can calculate the distance between two points using:

```
length = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2+(y1 - y2)^2).
```

However, I am uncertain as to where to go next. Should I use something from plyr or a for loop?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For which pairs exactly do you want to calculate the distance? Is there an x1, x2, y1 and y2 coordinate for each ID?

Comment: Hi Paul, no each ID is a point and I would like to calculate the distance between each point and  every other point

Comment: if you need output as a list of {x, y} combinations, you can start with `expand.grid`, if you prefer a matrix you should start with `dist`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried ?dist, the formula you listed is euclidean distance

```
dist(df[,-1])
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a self-join to get all combinations then apply your distance formula. All of this is easily do-able using the `tidyverse` (combination of packages from Hadley Wickham):

```
# Load the tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# Set up a fake key to join on (just a constant)
df <- df %>% mutate(k = 1) 

# Perform the join, remove the key, then create the distance
df %>% 
 full_join(df, by = "k") %>% 
 mutate(dist = sqrt((x.x - x.y)^2 + (y.x - y.y)^2)) %>%
 select(-k)
```

N.B. using this method, you'll also calculate the distance between each point and itself (as well as with all other points). It's easy to filter those points out though:

```
df %>% 
 full_join(df, by = "k") %>% 
 filter(ID.x != ID.y) %>%
 mutate(dist = sqrt((x.x - x.y)^2 + (y.x - y.y)^2)) %>%
 select(-k)
```

For more information about using the `tidyverse` set of packages I'd recommend [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) or the `tidyverse` [website](http://tidyverse.org/).

Comment: For anyone in the future looking at this. If you need to delete the duplicates (e.g. 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 will give the same distance), then here is a piece of (very ugly, but functional) code that you can use: 'IDx = df$ID.x
IDy = df$ID.y
length = df$length
df <- data.frame(IDx,IDy,length)
df <- data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, sort)))
df <- unique(df)
IDx = df$X2
IDy = df$X3
length = as.numeric(paste(df$X1))
df1 <- data.frame(IDx,IDy,length)'

Comment: @jim Leach I need the exact algorithm for my c++ implementation . I want to find the distance between each points and filter out duplicate points

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar not sure I can help there, sorry (I don't know C++!). But that distance calculation is the Euclidean distance so looking for that or some kind of distance matrix calculation in C++ is probably a safe bet.